# Error de sintaxis en función de MySQL

Tags: mysql

> 1º.- Crear una función llamada SACALETRA, que recibirá como parámetros una palabra de cómo máximo 15 letras y un número. Debe devolver la letra de la posición indicada en el número.

```
USE PRUEBA;
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sacaLetra $$
CREATE FUNCTION sacaLetra(letra VARCHAR(15), numero INT(15))
RETURNS VARCHAR(15)
RETURNS INT(15)
    BEGIN
        SET letra = LENGTH(letra);
        SET numero = numero;
        RETURN letra;
        RETURN numero;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe?

Comment: Realmente controlo mejor oracle que mysql pero así a simple vista, ese doble RETURN no pinta bien. Podrías plantearte usar variables de salida.

Comment: muchas gracias lo intentare cambiar

Comment: No había leído el enunciado de la pregunta. Creo que no lo estás planteando bien, realmente lo que deberías devolver es la letra en una posición en concreto. Por lo tanto, deberías tener un único return como varchar(1). Para calcular la letra podrías mirar la función [substr](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substr.asp)

Comment: muchas gracias lo acabo de realizar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo varias deficiencias en tu código.

Leamos el enunciado:

*Crear una función llamada SACALETRA, que recibirá como parámetros una palabra de cómo máximo 15 letras y un número. Debe devolver la letra de la posición indicada en el número.*

Si soy el profesor te daría quizá 50% por el esfuerzo, pero no es lo que se te ha pedido.

1. La supuesta solución no recibe un número como segundo parámetro
2. Los `SET` de los parámetros ya recibidos sobran
3. Dilapida datos: se pide un carácter en devolución, y tú le mandas un `VARCHAR(15)`
4. No controla errores (esto te lo perdonaría si no se ha tratado el tema en clases, si es así, olvida esa parte, pero en producción este tipo de cosas deben controlar los errores). El enunciado dice *una palabra de cómo máximo 15 letras*, por lo que se interpreta que esa condición debería ser controlada, no solamente definiendo el tamaño en el parámetro.

Aplicando lo dicho, la función podría quedar así:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sacaLetra $$
CREATE FUNCTION sacaLetra(letra VARCHAR(15), numero TINYINT)
    RETURNS CHAR(1) DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        SET @word_size = CHAR_LENGTH(letra);
        -- Verificar si tamaño no excede
        IF(@word_size < numero) THEN 
            -- Mensaje de eventual error
            SET @message_text = CONCAT(letra,' tiene un tamaño de: ',@word_size,' no se puede obtener la posición: ',numero);
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @message_text;
        ELSE
            RETURN CONCAT(SUBSTR(letra,numero,1));
        END IF;        
    END $$
```

---

Si no has visto en clases el control de errores, la función quedaría así:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sacaLetra $$
CREATE FUNCTION sacaLetra(letra VARCHAR(15), numero TINYINT)
    RETURNS CHAR(1) DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        RETURN CONCAT(SUBSTR(letra,numero,1));
    END $$
```

No obstante, una llamada como esta:

```
SELECT sacaLetra("Hola",30);
```

Producirá lo que yo llamo un código mudo, la nada, pantallazo en blanco, porque le estás pidiendo una posición `30` que no existe.

Comment: muchas gracias lo voy a mirra pero una duda si lo pongo varchar(15) son 15 caracteres no? y con eso controlo otra cosa y ahora quito los set muchas gracias por todo

Comment: @JavierG.Raya pero eso no evita que llames a la función asi por ejemplo: `SELECT sacaLetra("Hola",30);` Ahi le estarías pidiendo la posición `30`, la cual no existiría, si no controlas el error, te arrojará *nada*, un código mudo del cual esperas algo que en este caso no existe.

Comment: vale lo tendre en cuenta de momento no hemos visto como solucionar errores pero imaginos que sera con if elif ect

Comment: @JavierG.Raya al declarar el parámetro como `VARCHAR(15)` te controla que la cadena no tenga más de 15 carácteres, pero no hay control de que se pida un valor superior a ese en el segundo parámetro. Si no has visto el control de errores entonces puedes quitar la parte del `IF` y dejar el `RETURN` simplemente. Pero observa también que debes retornar un `CHAR(1)` que es lo que se está pidiendo en el enunciado, no un `VARCHAR(15)`. Lee también el asunto de `DETERMINISTIC` en el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html).

Comment: vale le echare un ojo

Answer (score 0):

Resulta que los parámetros debe ser el mismo tipo y un return y muchas gracias por su ayuda

```
# 1º.- Crear una función llamada SACALETRA, que recibirá como parámetros una palabra de cómo máximo 15 letras y un número. Debe devolver la letra de la posición indicada en el número.

USE PRUEBA;
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sacaLetra $$
CREATE FUNCTION sacaLetra(letra VARCHAR(15), numero VARCHAR(15))
RETURNS VARCHAR(15)

    BEGIN
        RETURN concat(SUBSTR(letra,numero,1));
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]